# Categorizing Data with SQL Statement to Import Data

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2

This is for SQL Server 2008 R2.

I have a table `PEOPLE` with a columns `NAME` and `AGE`. I am importing with a SQL Job to another table `LEADS` with the same columns `NAME` and `AGE`, and with an additional column, `AGEGROUP` where I want that

- Ages < 20 go into Group A
- Ages 21-39 go into Group B
- Ages 40-59 go into Group C
- Ages >= 60 go into Group D

How would that SQL Statement be?

Thanks.

Comment: why don't you store date of birth instead of age in the table, so that you can calculate age on the fly? any how below answers should work for your current model.

Comment: The reason is that the tool that will then process that data is some legacy thing that doesn't have that capacity. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This insert would do what you want (your logic would have missed anyone that was 20, so I put them in Group A)

```
INSERT INTO LEADS (NAME, AGE, AGEGROUP)
SELECT
    NAME
    , AGE
    , CASE 
        WHEN AGE <= 20 THEN 'A'
        WHEN AGE > 20 AND AGE < 40 THEN 'B'
        WHEN AGE >= 40 AND AGE < 60 THEN 'C'
        WHEN AGE >= 60 THEN 'D'
    END AS AGEGROUP         
FROM PEOPLE
```

Answer (score 2):

```
INSERT INTO LEADS (Name , Age , AgeGroup)
SELECT Name 
      ,Age 
      ,CASE WHEN Age <= 20 THEN 'A'
            WHEN Age > 20 AND Ages < 40 THEN 'B'
            WHEN Age >= 40 AND Ages < 60 THEN 'C'
            WHEN Age >=60  THEN 'D'
       END 
FROM People
```

Comment: Thanks. SnowWhite replied a few seconds before you! And besides, he/she has 289 points versus your 23.6k. Thanks a lot.